# How do you change the screen resolution in FreeBSD11 as a hyper-v guest?

Tags: xorg, freebsd, hyper-v

I'm running FreeBSD11 x64 as a Hyper-V guest and I'm having trouble finding information on how to increase the resolution to my monitor size (2560x1440 @ 144hz).

dmesg: http://pastebin.com/raw/UbbwHeBS

I've tried running

```
cvt 2560 1440 144

xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_144.00" 808.75 2560 2792 3072 3584 1440 1442 1448 1568 -hsync -vsync

xrandr --admode default 2560x1440_144.00

xrandr -s 2560x1440
```

but the output is "Failed to change the screen configuration!"

I've also tried setting up a custom resolution setting in xorg.conf.d to no avail.

Comment: You might want to put into your question what display modes `vidcontrol` says are available.

Comment: On the mailing list it was suggested I use VNC over the hyper-v console. This has proved to be a more than adequate solution